# How do you configure the users in Zabbix without using the frontent?

Tags: zabbix

I'm completely new to Zabbix.
How do I configure the users for Zabbix at startup?
Is there a configuration file somewhere.
Could someone point me to the relevant documentation? I only find 'frontend' documentation.

I only found something in the API at:
https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.4/en/manual/api/reference/user

But surely there's a configuration file somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

The users of the frontend are defined in the underlying database.

You can manage them from the GUI or you can provision them via API calls, using the API reference you've found.

You also have to consider the [authentication mode](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.4/en/manual/api/reference/authentication/object#authentication) if you want to provision SAML or LDAP users.